# Integration test with spock. Load context before first test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spock

Let's consider that very simple example that demonstrates my point:

```
@SpringBootTest
class Tmp extends Specification{

    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;

    def "getCarById"(int id) {
        return carService != null ? carService.getById(id) : new Car();
    }

    def "validate number of doors"(Car car, int expectedNrOfDoors) {
        expect:
        car.getNrOfDoors() == expectedNrOfDoors

        where:
        car               || expectedNrOfDoors
        getCarById(1)     || 3
        getCarById(2)     || 3
        getCarById(3)     || 5
    }
}
```

First `getCarById(_)` method will be called. Then context will be created, and then `validate number of doors` test will be executed. 
Is it possible to create the context "at the very beginning" ? in order to have access to it (and to `carService`) in `getCarById(_)` method ?

Comment: Place that code in constructor Tmp().

Comment: I don't follow. Could you elaborate on that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your example is that you try to access the `CarService` instance from the context in the `where` block. Code from the `where` block is used to create multiple tests at an early stage, quite close to the class loading.

I suggest to replace the `Car` parameter with just the car ID. Then you call `getCarById` in the `given` block. At that time the context will be loaded an `carService` is accessible.

```
@SpringBootTest
class Tmp extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private CarService carService

    def "validate number of doors"(int carId, int expectedNrOfDoors) {
        given:
        Car car = carService.getById(carId)

        expect:
        car.getNrOfDoors() == expectedNrOfDoors

        where:
        carId || expectedNrOfDoors
        1     || 3
        2     || 3
        3     || 5
    }
}
```